# Colab pro improvements and user feedback

Tags: google-colaboratory

few weeks ago i got a survey regarding what i expect or want from my colab pro subscription.
I was told they will be working to provide my requirements.

In the survey, it was written they'll be rolling out V100 GPU soon in colab pro.
I wanted to know when will it be available?

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this question as I was curious if there was any information regarding it, since I just found out today that my Colab instance had a V100. Looks like they're now rolling it out, which is super exciting.

Screen shot below. This is with normal runtime and not high-ram.

[Colab with V100 GPU using nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBGkf.png)